# Call Stack Priority in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

If 'A' goes into callback queue and 'B' and 'C' both still have to be executed, will A run after B (assuming that its timeout is complete), or will C run first?

I assume it will be A?

Comment: It's a queue. Which means it's FIFO - the events go in the order they entered. Unless you're flipping between the microtask and the macrotask queue, if the tasks that enter the queue are `B` -> `C` -> `A`, then the execution order would be `B` -> `C` -> `A`,

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how the title relates to the question. Are you asking about the call stack or the event queue?

Comment: I was asking about the interactions between both. Maybe a better question would have been 'Does an event in the queue have priority to return to the call stack, or an event that hasn't yet been passed to it?'

The concept is new to me, so my understanding probably isn't good enough to ask the question I wanted.

Comment: So, `function B() { setTimeout(A, 0), C() }`?

Comment: Hmm, no. I'll keep reading up. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof of concept.

```js
setTimeout(()=> console.log('C'), 500);
setTimeout(()=> console.log('B'), 500);


for (let i=0; i <= 99999; i++)
  for (let j=0; j <= 99999; j++)
    if (i === 9999 && j === 9999)    //< Note that the loop still continues after this
      setTimeout(()=> console.log('A'), 0); //Note the zero
```

Here is a guide:

https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-event-loop-and-the-rise-of-async-programming-5-ways-to-better-coding-with-2f077c4438b5

Answer (score 1):

When async operation ends the callback goes to the queue and wait there until call stack is empty. After that, the first callback from the queue is moving to call stack. So if there are B and C in the call stack and A is callback function waiting in the queue, A will be run after B and C.